# Can i extend a simple object class to create a Room database object?

Tags: android, android-room

Let's say i have a simple object class:

```
public class Test {

    public String teststring;

}
```

But then i'd like to create another object class, and this time it would be a Room Database class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "test_table_one")
public class TestChildOne extends Test {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public long test_id;

}
```

And then, i'd like to create another class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "test_table_two")
public class TestChildTwo extends Test {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public long test_id;

}
```

The issue here would be that the String `teststring` of the parent class wouldn't have a `@ColumnInfo` annotation. Fact is, I don't want to set an `@Entity` annotation in the parent class, since those two child classes would be of different tables, as you can see.

So, can I just set a `@ColumnInfo` in the parent class without `@Entity` set? Would it work then when I create an object `TestChildOne` and set `TestChildOne.teststring` or would it throw an error?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `@ColumnInfo` on teststring should work directly

Comment: Thank you @Redman, i'll try it out

Comment: @Redman it worked, you can write the solution if you wish and i'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: done added answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ColumnInfo` annotation will work even if it is in parent class ,so you can write `@ColumnInfo` even if class is not having `@Entity` annotation

```
public class Test {
     @ColumnInfo( name = "yourColumnName" )
    public String teststring;

}
```

Comment: you can simply add @ignor public String teststring and it will ignore to create column for this in the schema